# Publishing Azure Function don't publish host.json and all other folders in the project

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2017, continuous-deployment, azure-functions

I appreciate some help understanding what exaclly how Azure Function publishing works.

This is my project

[image]

1. While publishing(from vs or Github CI\CD) my "App_data" folder don't get pushed into the project
2. I edited my host file how-ever while publishing an empty host.json is created on the Azure Function

Does someone can explain why is it happning and how can i resolve it ?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: publishing from VS is very different from Github CI\CD. In VS the build happens on your machine and artifacts are pushed to the server, in CI\CD scenario you check in your code, and it get's pulled, build and deployed on the server. Can you explain a bit more which one you were exactly using and what you observed

Comment: I want to use the CI\CD not the manual vs, All of my folders and files that are not .cs not get deployed into the wwwroot directory

Comment: I don't think there is automatic detection of the new VS 2017 function app project. This PR is adding it (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/pull/2454, https://github.com/projectkudu/KuduScript/pull/84) but I don't think it's deployed yet. You can use a custom deployment script for that or run kuduscript with the parameters specified in the PR https://github.com/projectkudu/KuduScript/pull/84